# jQuery 'POST' Authorization

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, authorization

I used jquery-ajax method POST to post authorization headers, but Firebug show an error "401 Unauthorized" headers as parameters of the method.

What am I doing wrong? And what should I do?

```
jQuery(function(dat) {
dat.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: {
    Latlng: 'coordinates.coordinates',
    texts: 'text'
  },
  success: function(dat) {
    setMarkers(dat);
  },
  dataType: "json"
});
});
```

And this is oAuth method I forgot (I don't think here is something wrong because I made it as in example.)

> var url = "https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json";
>       var accessor = {
>         token: "token",
>         tokenSecret: "token_secret",
>         consumerKey : "consumer_key",
>         consumerSecret: "consumer_secret"
>       };
>
> ```
> var message = {
>   action: url,
>   method: "POST",
>   parameters: {
>     track: 'nutella',
>     locations: '-180,-90,180,90'
>   }
> };
> ```
>
> OAuth.completeRequest(message, accessor);
>   OAuth.SignatureMethod.sign(message, accessor);   url = url + '?' +
>   OAuth.formEncode(message.parameters);

I closed secret data.

Comment: Have you checked the request headers in the firebug? Are they correct?

Comment: @zerkms, No. They are wrong. Actually, there are no 'Authorization'-headers.

Comment: @user1499804: so, yes, show how exactly you're doing that and look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/9613117/251311

Comment: @Wolfram I am trying to authorize my app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Basic Auth and Jquery and Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-and-jquery-and-ajax)

Answer (score 6):

You have to send an additional header.  I know if you are trying to call google api they ask for a header titled Authorization. Here is how you would do that via jQuery.

```
function setHeader(xhr) {

 xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', '12345');
 xhr.setRequestHeader('SomethingElse', 'abcdefg');

}

$.ajax({

        url: 'www.google.com',
    type: 'POST',
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function() { alert("Success"); },
    error: function() { alert('Failure!'); },
    beforeSend: setHeader

});
```

Comment: But Twitter Streaming API suggests oAuth. And I am trying authorize exactly this.

Comment: Whatever header you need to send that's how you would do it.  XMLHttpRequest (this is what you are sending) sets headers in this way.  Just a Key value pair.

Comment: Twitter does have samples so just see what they are doing there.